# How to reset usual $query on search page to push custom $wpdb query there?

Tags: query, search, pre-get-posts

I, recently posted 2 questions ([First](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188060/how-to-make-an-author-archive-only-for-certain-user-role-and-show-related-cpt), [Second](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188629/modifying-default-search-by-including-the-users-additionally)) with no answer. I found my solution for both of them. But now it's time to fine-tune things. If I can fine-tune here, I could answer both the questions. Why to fine-tune? Because the [procedural raw PHP coding](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165494/22728) is less prior to [WordPress' way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176805/22728).

```
<?php
function project_modify_default_search( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() && ! isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) ) {
        //I'm in my search.php - confirmed

        //Reset default $query - not to execute at all

        //Do my custom complex query and pass the query as a $wp_query object
        //so that I can use the default search.php template
        global $wpdb;
        $searchQ = sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( 's' ) );
        $complex_query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS {$wpdb->posts}.ID ...";
        return $custom_search_query = $wpdb->get_results( $complex_query, ARRAY_N );

    } //endif
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'project_modify_default_search' );
```

But actually I'm failing with the code above in two cases:

- I can't reset default query
- I can't return my custom query so that I can grab that the default `search.php` works flawlessly

But the query is working, I checked that other way.

Question is:
**How can I reset the usual $query on the search page to initiate my custom `$wpdb` query there?**

Comment: You want both the default search and your custom one?

Comment: No. I want my custom one over the default one. As I'm not modifying the default one, but querying a new, so I need to shut the default one off, and pass the new one to that page in a way that, in `search.php` with `if( have_posts() )` simply can have it like default query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how `pre_get_posts` works.

> The pre_get_posts action gives developers access to the $query object
>   by reference (***any changes you make to $query are made directly to the
>   original object - no return value is necessary***).
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

What you are doing is simply wrong. You don't "return" another query via `pre_get_posts`, you alter the existing query. I don't know what is so complex you can't do it via an appropriate set of filters but if you must have some custom SQL then:

```
function project_modify_default_search( $query ) {
  if( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() && ! isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) ) {

    //I'm in my search.php - confirmed

    //Reset default $query - not to execute at all

    //Do my custom complex query and pass the query as a $wp_query object
    //so that I can use the default search.php template
    global $wpdb;
    $searchQ = sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( 's' ) );

    // Sample "complex" query
    $complex_query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '$searchQ%' LIMIT 10";

    // Use `get_col` to return a simple array of IDs
    $custom_search_query = $wpdb->get_col( $complex_query );

    // Pass those IDs to the main query
    $query->set('post__in',$custom_search_query);

    // can't kill the default search here or it can break some functions.
    // $query->set('s',NULL);

    // So we do this:
    add_action( 'posts_search', '__return_empty_string' );

  } //endif
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'project_modify_default_search' );
```

Again, pretty sure this is the wrong way to generate a complicated query, especially given that you have at least one extra query relative to modifying the main query via a set of filters-- `posts_where`, `posts_join`, etc.

Comment: It's working just fine. But if nothing is found, instead of returning false it's returning all the posts. How can I stop them? I even tried `if( $custom_search_query ) $query->set('post__in',$custom_search_query);`, but not working

Comment: @MayeenulIslam when `$complex_query` return nothing, the `'post__in'` query variable is ignored because empty. The `'s'` query does nothing because of `add_action( 'posts_search', '__return_empty_string' )`. It means the query runs with no constraints thus it returns all posts. My suggestion is to replace the whole request that WP_Query performs by using [`'posts_request'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_request/) filter hook.